# Cannot install HTML-CSS-JS Prettify for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I have ST3. Clicked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, selected Install Package, inserted package name "HTML-CSS-JS Prettify" clicked on it.

Nothing happens. Later, when I select <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, and List Packages, its not there.

Why, whats wrong.

Comment: any errors in the ST console? (View menu -> Show Console)

Comment: no, no errors, nothing